# почему то посреди кода просто пропускается четный индекс, задание из checkio

Tags: python

там где assert все норм, но в строчке, кт я перед example написал, ответ получается -1476, а не 1968. Пробовал с помощью отладки посмотреть, что не так, а там индекс именно числа "84"(т.е. 16) проверку на четность индекса не проходит и код его пропускает.

само задание:

"Дан массив целых чисел. Нужно найти сумму элементов с четными индексами (0-й, 2-й, 4-й итд), затем перемножить эту сумму и последний элемент исходного массива. Не забудьте, что первый элемент массива имеет индекс 0.

Для пустого массива результат всегда 0 (ноль)."

```py
def checkio(array: list[int]) -> int:
    if not array:
        return 0
    a = []
    for i in array:
        if array.index(i) % 2 == 0:
            a.append(i)
    return sum(a)*array[-1]

print(checkio([-37, -36, -19, -99, 29, 20, 3, -7, -64, 84, 36, 62, 26, -76, 55, -24, 84, 49, -65, 41])) #должно в итоге получиться 1968
print("Example:")
print(checkio([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

# These "asserts" are used for self-checking
assert checkio([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == 30
assert checkio([1, 3, 5]) == 30
assert checkio([6]) == 36
assert checkio([]) == 0

print("The mission is done! Click 'Check Solution' to earn rewards!")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что метод `index` возвращает позицию первого вхождения элемента. В списке `[-37, -36, -19, -99, 29, 20, 3, -7, -64, 84, 36, 62, 26, -76, 55, -24, 84, 49, -65, 41]` у вас дублируется элемент `84`, поэтому сумма считается неправильно.

Поправьте функцию

```
def checkio(array: list[int]) -> int:
    if not array:
        return 0
    a = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            a.append(array[i])
    return sum(a)*array[-1]
```

Результат:

```
1968
Example:
30
The mission is done! Click 'Check Solution' to earn rewards!
```

Comment: Честно говоря, непонятно, зачем перебирать все индексы и проверять их чётность, если в `range` можно сразу указать шаг перебора. )

Answer (score 1):

А вообще можно гораздо короче написать, в одну строку, используя тернарный оператор и срез с шагом 2:

```
def checkio(array: list[int]) -> int:
    return 0 if not array else sum(array[::2] * array[-1])
```

Comment: да, точно, я чет все мега усложнил